# Scanning and distributing/sorting paper files fast

Tags: scanning

I looked a bit into scanning & filing systems like neat.com or paperless(-ng) but what both are missing is a step during scanning that pre-sorts the scan.

Most of the time one probably scans only a few documents types: receipts, holiday requests, paper notes etc. So one could prepare folders (in a DMS) für each type. If the scanner dialog asks you which type a scan is and the just pushes the document to the folder, it would make things much simpler imho.

Another version would also be possible, where you make a foto of a document, put a little barcode beside it, which gets recognized be the foto app  and again pushes the doc into a preset folder. That would also enable other people to send you scanned files quickly from other PCs in the network.

Has anyone ever seen something similar?

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

I recommend also looking into apps like [NAPS2](https://www.naps2.com/doc-command-line.html) or [Paperless-CLI](https://github.com/stgarf/paperless-cli), that offer command-line interfaces. Hence you can possibly do some of the pre-sorting via a script.